# Websockets-Rails gives "eventmachine not initialized" error in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have recently started using the websocket-rails gem and all is fine in development and even in production, but when I run rspec tests I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 RuntimeError:
   eventmachine not initialized: evma_install_oneshot_timer
```

The message seems to appear on the second test I run. When I run a previously failing test on it's own by adding `:focus => true` to the test and then `rspec --tag focus` its passes OK. If I add the focus to more than one test, usually the first one passes and the second test gives the error.

I am using rspec Capybara with the Selemium web driver. I think this may be to do with the web server in test not being an "eventmachine based web server" but I am not 100% sure. I have tried setting up the websockets server as standalone by adding the following in my websocket initializer `config.standalone = true` and then starting the server by `rake websocket_rails:start_server RAILS_ENV=test`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by configuring rspec to use the Thin server by adding the following within my spec_helper.rb file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Capybara.server do |app, port|
    require 'rack/handler/thin'
    Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => port)
  end

  #other configuration here....
end
```